# Install calabash-android ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I'm new in [Calabash](http://calaba.sh), and I would like detailed how to if possible for install and run calabash-android on Ubuntu 16.04, please.

I already have install android studio, but I'm stuck on install ruby using rvm and gem install calabash-android.

I really could not find videos or how to about installing calabash-android on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You need Ruby, Java, and Android SDK first... How far have you gotten with that? https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md

Comment: @cricket_007 All installed.

Comment: And gem install has errors, or...?

Comment: Can you post some of the error logs that you get when you attempt to install calabash-android?
Can you also verify that you've got a valid ruby installed? I.e. run `ruby -v` in the terminal (it should ideally be greater than 2.1.5)